# Android Seekbar thumb onclick listener

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have made my music app and now I need to make music play/pause control on seekbar. Here's the image [image]

As you can see there's `seekbar` with custom thumb image and when user touch thumb music start's to play or stop's Is it possible to implement something similar like that? Basically I need to implement listener only for `seekbar` thumb. I know how to get thumb from `seekbar` however thumb is `drawable` so I can't implement any listener. `audioSeekBar.getThumb()`

Comment: what about the SeekBarChangeListener?

Comment: @ Opiatefuchs `SeekBarChangeListener` triggers when seekbar is touched what I need is somehow know when seekbar THUMB is touched

Comment: really as special as this? So you want to add a function that is not happening when the seekbar is pressed, only when the thumb is pressed, correct?

Comment: @ Opiatefuchs, Yes that's exactly what I need.

Comment: So there is no such method, but I guess you can make a workaround by monitor the position. For example, make an onTouchListener which allows to seek if the motion event is ACTION_MOVE and listen to ACTION_DOWN/ACTION_UP ......

Answer (score 1):

You should listen touchEvent, calculate where is that touch is on seekbar thumb and prevent click event from being invoked when user moved seekbar, but not clicked.

Sth like this:

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        float prevX = Float.MIN_VALUE;
        float eps = 0.001f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Drawable drawable = seekBar.getThumb();

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                if (event.getX() >= drawable.getBounds().left && event.getX() <= drawable.getBounds().right
                        && event.getRawY() >= drawable.getBounds().top && event.getRawY() >= drawable.getBounds().bottom) {
                    prevX = event.getX();
                }
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (event.getX() >= drawable.getBounds().left && event.getX() <= drawable.getBounds().right
                        && event.getRawY() >= drawable.getBounds().top && event.getRawY() >= drawable.getBounds().bottom) {
                    if (Math.abs(event.getX() - prevX) < eps) {
                        Log.d("here", "clicked on place");
                    }
                }
                prevX = Float.MIN_VALUE;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```